# Randomly losing connection but still in LAN

Tags: wireless, networking, lan

At work I am using ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop.

Throughout the day I randomly lose connection to the internet, but I am still in the WLAN.

Like, when I try to connect to google it will timeout and not do anything.  Then after about 30 seconds I will be able to connect to google again.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this may be happening?  There is a coffee shop next door and I can connect to it and surf the internet all day without having any issues.

Is it possible that someone is de-authenticating me?  In this case, wouldn't I also lose connection to the WLAN?  Is it possible to use wireshark to see is this is happening?

Kindest Regards,

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your works networking. Is anyone else on the same LAN experiencing similar issues?

Comment: dan08, no other computers in the network are experiencing issues like this.  Also, all are windows machines.  Thank you for your response.